# Sending Facebook app request using Tornado Framework

Tags: facebook, request, message, tornado

I am a student majoring in CS and very newbie to Facebook app development. I couldn't find any good resources online so, I was wondering how can I send an app request or a message using python tornado framework to targeted user? So far, I have my app access token but I couldn't get app request to work... I need some kind of reference to follow but I am not having good time finding one that is "SIMPLE" enough... Thanks!

Comment: Is the Tornado framework a requirement to be used? Anytime you try to use a 3rd party API, it's going to be tough.  Why not use one of the APIs from Facebook such as the Javascript API?

Comment: Yes I would love to use Javascript API but... the place I am currently working (intern) needs Tornado Framework =(

Comment: I'm not sure many people around here know of the Tornado framework for Facebook.  I've never heard of it before.  Can you post a link to documentation on this Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the backend framework, doing app invites is all client-side, so as long as you can stream out HTML from your server with the correct Javascript, then you'll be well on your way.

See:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ For information and examples can be found and played with in Javascript tool at: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/ click `Examples`, then click `apprequests`

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am a bit curious where the Javascript tool is at =( I don't see any 'Examples', 'apprequests' link =(

Comment: Sorry, bad copy/paste on my part.  I've edited it above to include the correct URL.